# Identify differentially expressed genes across genotypes

Tags: generalized-linear-model, t-test, genetics, bioinformatics

I have 40 different genotypes of rice. For each genotype, I have two replicates under control treatment and two replicates under drought treatment. We sequenced those samples and get read counts of around 50000 genes. We did differentially expression analysis with DEseq for each genotype individually. However, the overlap of DE genes is small. So we would like to find a test that could tell us which gene could be regarded as DE genes across those genotypes.

I have some ideas and don't know which one works best. Could someone give me some suggestions? 
1. Using permutation: the null hypothesis would be there's no difference between control and treatment.

2. using ANOVA: treat genotype as a random effect
   SAS code:
   class treatment genotype;
   model count = treatment;
   random genotype;
3. using Generalized linear mixed model: the response~negative binomial distribution and treat genotype as a random effect

class treatment genotype;
model count = treatment/dist=negabin;
random genotype;

Since I will do the same test for around 50000 genes, I still need an adjusted p value. What R package can I use for this test? Thanks!

Comment: When you say you got read counts for 50,000 genes, exactly what does that mean ? I work with Arabidopsis that has a genome of about 32,000 genes. Typically, you are not going to get reads in all genes. How come you used DESeq and not DESeq2 ? About how many differentially expressed genes per genotype are you getting when you have a q value (False Discovery Rate) of 0.05 ? I would think there should be considerable overlap of differentially expressed genes between genotypes.